# Django: how to pass an entire URL as a parameter inside the app URL?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to pass an entire, full length/structure URL within my app as an argument inside the app's URL. For example, I want to be able to do something like:
`myapp.com/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ` so that I can take the URL entered after my app's home page and store it. However, I think the app is getting confused when the URL pasted has fragments and query arguments (ie: contains # and/or ?) My urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<url_param>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-/:?=#]*)/$', views.anywebsiteentered, name='anywebsiteentered')
```

When I try to write a view that looks like below to take the inputted URL and save it inside a model object, I always get the URL truncated before the query and fragment characters, what can I do so that my application picks up the entire URL string?

```
def anywebsiteentered(request, url_param = 'url_param'):
    UrlBlob.objects.create(fullurl=url_param)
```

For example, the above object created if my app is at `myapp.com/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ` only returns `https://www.youtube.com/watch` and not the query part of the URL. I suspect it is something I am doing with the passing of the URL because when I create this model object manually inside the python-django shell there is no problems at all.

Thanks for any help and hints. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you needed to use some url in "path" area of another url you should escape it's special characters. For example use %3F instead "?". It's called url escaping.

For your purpose would be better pass url as argument like:

```
myapp.com/?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

— browser will do necessary escaping in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am open to trying it like this. How would my urls.py for something like this look? Would it be the exact same as what I have posted up there?

Comment: In urls.py you can capture only "path" area of url. This is `/` in my example and you can use simple `r'^/$'` regular expression. Url "args" will pass to a view in `request` object like `request.GET["url"]`.

Comment: Thanks, just tried it and it worked really well, except for one thing. Fragment strings that start with # do not get captured still. Do you know why that might be? For example, this comment's url contains a fragment but when I enter it in your expression myapp.com/?url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250089/django-how-to-pass-an-entire-url-as-a-parameter-inside-the-app-url/28250308?noredirect=1#comment44860412_28250308 it and I use request.GET['url'] it stops after the noredirect=1 part.

Comment: Browser doesn't send to server rest of url located after fragment identifier `#`. The only way to send it to server is to force escaping `#` as `%23`.

Comment: Darn. Well thanks for the response then. I think I'll opt to use your method for capturing most of the URL. I guess I'll have to figure out the escaping since I really do need the entire entered URL no exceptions, the queries, the params, the fragments, the scheme etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the query string from `request.META`:

```
def anywebsiteentered(request, url_param='url_param'):

    full_url = url_param
    query_string = request.META['QUERY_STRING']
    if query_string:
        full_url += u'?' + query_string

    UrlBlob.objects.create(fullurl=full_url)
```

Comment: This is a possible method as well. I could just turn the entire URL argument into a query string itself like suggested in the first answer to this thread like: myapp.com/?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ but that answer does not capture URL fragments or URL params in the URL. Can your method be used to capture not just queries but also fragments and params of the entered url as well?

Comment: Sure you could. Moreover, imho the first answer is a better option.  I just showed you an alternative way.

Comment: Ya, I think I will use the first way, but opt to use your alternate method to grab the fragment string from the entered URL. Thank you for showing this way to me. Is the syntax to request the fragment string simply request.META['FRAGMENT_STRING']

Comment: Look for the list of widely used request meta headers: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META